# What do I have to push to github to update my octopress blog?

Tags: git, github, blogs, octopress

I just created a blog that is hosted on github. Now I made some customizations locally on my machine and now would like to bring them to github. In the documentation ( http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/ ) octopress says that you have to commit the generated content to the master branch.

Call me dumb but I don't get. What do I have to commit? My source code or my code in my _deploy folder? And to which branch do I have to push my content?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

You need to push the content of `public`. Unless you explicitly do something to copy the data from `public` to `_deploy`, `_deploy` will be empty.

You can simplify this by using the the rake task `setup_github_pages` once and after that deploy via `rake deploy`.

Comment: @user1420042: What are you trying to say with that comment? My answer tells you how to update your blog.

Comment: What I wrote in my answer. *READ* it.

Comment: but public does not contain a .git

Comment: That has nothing to do with pushing the content. You surely have to execute that to generate the content though. Why don't you just go ahead and play with it?